# The question is still in search results, even though the tags were changed

Tags: bug, tags, search

I use the following search query to filter out those questions which are tagged with e.g. [sitecore-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-mvc) or [sitecore8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore8), but not the main one - [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore):

```
[sitecore6*] or [sitecore7*] or [sitecore8*] or [sitecore-*] -[sitecore] is:question
```

Works just fine, but [this (only one) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414602/sitecore-removing-documents-from-solr) is still in search results even though I modified the tags (added [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore)) quite some time ago.

Looks like a bug. If my search query is the problem, please point it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably cache.

Give it a couple of minutes, then run the query again. The edited question should disappear from the results, eventually.

For me, the question you linked is not showing in [that search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsitecore6*%5D%20or%20%5Bsitecore7*%5D%20or%20%5Bsitecore8*%5D%20or%20%5Bsitecore-*%5D%20-%5Bsitecore%5D%20is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Strange... it usually works the way you describe, but this one always shows up in the search for a couple of weeks. I ended up editing it again - just removing and adding back a tag. Looks like that "awoke" the cache mechanism and it doesn't show up now... Anyway, thanks for your answer.